# Geometry Nodes - limit Instance Geometry on points with Selection

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

How can I instance object on points of another geometry, but **limit number of points used**? Here is my current node set up:

[image]

I want to use the **Selection socket on Instance on Points node**, but I have no idea how to use it. I tried Noise Textures, Random Values and can't figure out how to randomly limit number of points used?

Is there a way to get ID / Index of each point and then randomly select 40% of them for the Selection, to Instance Cubes on the base Mesh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just plug this into your selection of your point instance node:

[image]

This won't give the "exact" amount, but a good approximation.

Comment: Chris, this is super simple - I tried Random Value, but with Float and trying some gymnastics with ID, but it was not working. 

This is super easy and efficient. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Chris answer is simple and efficient way to "cut" through number of instances on points randomly.

There is a different way, if you want to have some pattern / texture, when instancing on your base mesh. Somehow, when I first tried doing this with Noise textures, I did not try it with Noise + Color Ramp nodes and it did not work.

Here how it looks now:

[image]

**Noise Texture with Color Ramp**:

[image]

**Musgrave Texture with Color Ramp** and so on:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!